# obj-c writing string to file not working

Tags: ios, nsstring, writetofile

I have the following attempt to write a string to a file on the desktop, but I'm getting an error.

The code I have written is:

```
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

// Get array with first index being path to desktop
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// Get the first element
NSString *desktopPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Append words.txt to path
NSString *theFilePath = [desktopPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"glutenFreeJson.txt"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@\n\n", jsonString);
NSLog(@"%@\n\n", theFilePath);
[jsonString writeToFile:theFilePath atomically:YES encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
NSLog(@"Write returned error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

This prints "`Write returned error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)`"

I'm not sure why.

Update: the app originally requested json data from a server, parsed it, and displayed it.  However, the server has been iffy and doesn't always respond promptly and I only need the data once, so I just want to download it to my desktop folder on my computer and move it into my project folder.

Comment: What is the iOs Desktop path in your understanding (as you are using `NSDesktopDirectory`) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no DesktopDirectory in iOS ,change `NSDesktopDirectory` to `NSDocumentDirectory`. It'll work.

or Simple write

```
NSString *desktopPath = NSHomeDirectory();
```

Comment: That's not exactly correct, you can get **some** path at `/var/mobile/` with `NSDesktopDirectory`, that will be `NSHomeDirectory()` + `/Desktop`, neither are writable.

Comment: @A-Live: `NSDocumentDirectory` returns `/Users/Midhun/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/24E2D0D1-D918-4949-AF07-B6293D115FE9/Library/Documentation` `NSHomeDirectory()` Returns `/Users/Midhun/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/24E2D0D1-D918-4949-AF07-B6293D115FE9`

Comment: @A-Live: I didn't understand what you mean by `NSHomeDirectory() + /Desktop` ?

Comment: by '+' I meant concatenation. As I said, writing anything to root NSHomeDirectory() is prohibited. NSDocumentDirectory was not in your original answer, I'm glad you've added it but the answer still incorrect as it suggests writing to NSHomeDirectory().

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Comment: I've edited my post, as the intention was to write to the desktop of my computer.